# laravel-5.4 - error :Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, database, image, authentication, laravel-5.4

I want to store image path in database. My Controller code under`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php` follows:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();              
    $image_path = $request->file('image')->store('public'); 
    $user->image = Storage::url($image_name);
    $user->save();
    }

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

   // $this->guard()->login($user); disable autologin for new users

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

I am getting the following error: ErrorException in RegistersUsers.php line 40: Creating default object from empty value [image].

The  image is getting saved in public folder but not able to save image path in the user table database. schema of user table
      `Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();`

how to proceed to store the image path in the user table in database

Comment: how do you implement your `create` method?

Answer (score 11):

you haven't initialized the variable `$user` so in the controller and before using it you've to add `$user = new User;` assuming that you already have `use App\User;`

or `$user = new \App\User;` if you don't.

**Update**
if you're trying to update an existing user record you've to initialize the `$user` variable by selecting based on it's primary key which should be sent in the request and then doing the initialization like:

```
$user_id = $request->input('user_id');
$user = User::find($user_id);
```

Comment: he's using it as a laravel user object so that he can easily use ` $user->save();`

Comment: I have `use App\User;` n code already. I dont have to do `$user =new User;` n code because this public function register-> Handle a registration request for the application. means i already got user name and image registered and doing validation.`$this->validator($request->all())->validate();`. if I do $user =new User , then i will be inserting new value to the user.  in the database i have an entry for image which is now "C:\xampp\tmp\php469E.tmp". My need is to update the tmp path to public folder path.

Comment: inside `register` function's scope there's no variable `$user` so it's not defined. Are trying to update a user record ?

Comment: Yes.Updating the  image in user record in database.If you check the error image which i uploaded-> I am updating the image in user table in database with image path instead of tmp path

Answer (score 2):

Use the simple way below:

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', $id)->first(); // where id is method param from url or request object
$user->save();
```

This is also easier when updating multiple tables where the ids in the sub-tables have foreign keys and need to be explicitly defined in the update process.

Also `$user = User::find($id);` normally work where the `$id` is the primary key of that object table