# I seems cant to save my Uploaded file to database LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

hello im trying to save my filename in database laravel , but it gives me
im doing upload image with laravel. The image is uploaded yet the field from my rent database not. This is what happens.

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

im using Storage:link

Controller
    use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

```
public function insertproof(Request $request)
    $id = $request['id'];
    if ($request->hasFile('rent_proof')){
        $filepath = $request->file('rent_proof')->store('app/folder_proof');
    }
    $result = rent::find($id);
    $result->rent_proof=$filepath;
    $result->save();
}
```

and here is my view and this view is from mymodal

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('visitor_rent.insertproof')}}"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="rent_proof"  id="proof">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

This is my model

```
public class Rent extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['rent_proof'];
}
```

edit :
hello this one that gives me the error

```
    $result = rent::find($id);
    $result->rent_proof=$filepath; //<--this line is giving me the error
    $result->save();
```

thanks for the care
is there anything that i miss?

Version laravel 5.5
PHP 7.2

Comment: if your -1 help you make your days better its fine. im still a nob and i need guidance, its fine -1 me but at least try to tell me what is my fault. here is same case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488754/laravel-5-4-error-creating-default-object-from-empty-value but still not answered too, i need someone to pin point what my missing things, i can continue after that even you dont provide me any code at all..

Comment: Someone has -1 your question because the question is not obvious. Now tell me what exactly are you gonna achieve and what is the exact error. and I will re-edit your question as the community can understand the real situation. I'm trying to help, and i'm not the one who -1 your question :)

Comment: hello sir yes i found that i not bound the error code that whoops throw, thanks for the feed back, it makes me a better person

Comment: In Laravel exception trace, It provides you the exact line number which has thrown the error.

Comment: `$result = rent::find($id);` , looks like `$result` is `NULL` ,, are you sure the value `$id` is exist in table ?

Comment: try this code set. `try { $result->rent_proof=$filepath; } catch (\Exception $e) { dd( $result, $filepath ); }` now figure out which one is null?

Comment: hello guys thanks for the patient time, after i dd my id. it returns me null. Long story short, the problem is actually reside on my view page within jquery. Which a super nob mistake because i trust that $id = $request['id']; is give me correct id. Thanks guys GBU all. Sorry not replying fast, i dont want to burden you guys too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Creating default object from empty value` this error is because id which you have passed doesn't exists in your database.

if you are creating a new record with id and image path

then you should use

```
$result = new Rent;
$result->rent_proof=$filepath; //<--this line is giving me the error
$result->save();
```

If you are updating existed one then pass proper id which exists in database

Comment: Hello, thanks for the feedback! the error comes from $id = $request['id']; because im using javascript to transfer data to myModal yet it returns null, so i make it work, sorry for the late reply and newbie mistakes. Thanks and GBU!